# Use SQL INSERT to insert multiple records from two lists

Tags: sql-server

I have a list of employee numbers and a list of dates.  I want to insert a row into a table for each employee number and date.

- EMPNUM (1, 2, 3 ,4, 5)
- DATES ('2020-04-06', '2020-04-07', '2020-04-08', '2020-04-09', '2020-04-10')

I could use:

```
BEGIN TRAN
SET XACT_ABORT ON

INSERT INTO TABLE1 (EMPNUM, DATE)
VALUES (1, '2020-04-06')
       (1, '2020-04-07')
       etc.
```

but that will require creating an extraordinary number of records manually.

Is there an easier way to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cross join` with values construct :

```
insert into table1 (empnum, date)
   select e.empnum, d.dates
   from (values(1), (2), (3), (4), (5) 
        ) e(empnum) cross join
        (values ('2020-04-06'), ('2020-04-07'), ('2020-04-08'), ('2020-04-09') 
        ) d(dates);
```

Comment: Tried a cross join based on the above but got an error,  'e' has more columns than were specified in the column list.

Comment: @Kevin_H. . . Problem with `SELECT` statement, it contains more column  than column defined in `INSERT INTO` statement.

Comment: I tweaked my code and it worked perfectly so thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a CROSS JOIN, eg

```
with empnums as
(
  select cast(value as int) empnum from openjson('[1,2,3,4,5,6]')
), dates as
(
  select cast(value as date) date from openjson('["20200406","20200407","20200408","20200409"]')
)
select *
from empnums
cross join dates
```